# Get the SQLException java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called

Tags: java, oracle, soap, sqlexception

I'm developing a Webservice at the moment. I thought I was ready to release my first productive version but I keep getting a SQLException which doesn't make any sense to me. I'm developing against a Oracle db btw. 
Let me give you my code at first:

```
try{
    variable = DoQuery("SELECT KEY FROM TABLE WHERE KEY IN ('KEY1', 'KEY2') AND ROWNUM = 1").getString("HANDLE");
}catch(SQLException e){
    return "Wasn't able to gather key: " + e.toString() + " - " + e.getSQLState();
}
```

The method "DoQuery":

```
private ResultSet DoQuery(String sqlString){
    Statement sqlHandleStatement;
    try {
        sqlHandleStatement = getStatement();
        return sqlHandleStatement.executeQuery(sqlString);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The method "getStatement":

```
private Statement getStatement() throws SQLException {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        dataSource = (DataSource) JNDIUtils.getInitialContext().lookup(JNDIUtils.DEFAULT_DATASOURCE);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection;

    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement statement;
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    return statement;
}
```

However if I execute my SOAP request I keep getting back:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:getNextRMANumberResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.epm.com/">
         <return>Wasn't able to gather key: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called - 99999</return>
      </ns2:getNextRMANumberResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Error message: "Wasn't able to gather key: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called - 99999" (compare to the very first code snippet given in this post)

What does this mean? I really don't get why I should execute "ResultSet.next"?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must call "next" and then the "getString" function to set the resultset's cursor onto the first row.

```
try{
    ResultSet resuse = DoQuery("SELECT KEY FROM TABLE WHERE KEY IN ('KEY1', 'KEY2') AND ROWNUM = 1");
    resuse.next();
    variable = resuse.getString("KEY");
}catch(SQLException e){
    return "Wasn't able to gather key: " + e.toString() + " - " + e.getSQLState();
}
```

The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) states:

> Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.

Comment: If I would call next() on at first I would get a boolean and so can't call the "getString" method.

Comment: ResultSet rs = sqlStatement.executeQuery(someQuery); rs.next(); rs.getString("HANDLE");

Comment: Like this:     try{
        ResultSet resuse = DoQuery("SELECT KEY FROM TABLE WHERE KEY IN ('KEY1', 'KEY2') AND ROWNUM = 1");
        resuse.next();
        variable = resuse.getString("KEY");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        return "Wasn't able to gather key: " + e.toString() + " - " + e.getSQLState();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from ResultSet API: A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row

Answer (score 0):

From Official JavaDoc: -

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown. If the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, it is vendor specified whether their JDBC driver implementation will return false or throw an SQLException on a subsequent call to next.
>
> If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method next will implicitly close it. A ResultSet object's warning chain is cleared when a new row is read.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Resultset.next()` not extracted error coming  means you not called explicitly that is you write like this your problem will be solved
first of all check `resltset` is null or not

```
if(rs!=null){
while(rs.next()){
-------process the results
}//while loop
}//if
```