# Web Application not working on Tomcat hosted on Solaris Machine

Tags: java, solaris

I am trying to debug a Java Web Application which basically removes data from one set of tables and create it in another set of table in  same DataBase(Oracle).
This Web application is hosted on Apache Tomcat(6.0.26) on Solaris Machine(s10s_u8wos_o8a).
**But on Solaris this application is not working and throws error randomly.
Important thing is that when I use the same WAR File on Apache Tomcat hosted on Windows or Linux Machine, it works perfectly.**

I am getting following exception:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:962)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:494)
    at com.vf.IVRmigrate.CallPlanUpdater.migrate(Updater.java:85)
    at com.vf.IVRmigrate.IVRMigrate.runMigrate(Migrate.java:334)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.RunMigrate_jsp._jspService(Migrate_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at   
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at 
   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)`
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**I am of the opinion that there is some resource scarce on Solaris platform.**

Can anybody help in getting to the root of the problem?

Regards

Comment: *But on Solaris this application is not working and throws error randomly. Important thing is that when I use the same WAR File on Apache Tomcat hosted on Windows or Linux Machine,it works perfectly.*  I hope you realize that does not mean your application is correct.  In fact, it most likely means the opposite - you have a problem, but you just get away with it on Windows and Linux. *I am of the opinion that there is some resource scarce on Solaris platform.*  Maybe. But you need to provide a lot more information for anyone to even try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Have you looked through database logs?  Your Tomcat logs?  Where is the actual database?  How do you access it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, unable to add a comment (low reputation)...

It could be your tomcat env in win maybe up to date with dependencies etc... And Solaris env not so...

In any case, I see that this was discussed in another thread... You may want to refer to that (if you haven't already done that)... The root cause of why this happens may provide you with clues...

[Get the SQLException java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828015/get-the-sqlexception-java-sql-sqlexception-resultset-next-was-not-called)

one more...
[ResultSet .next was not called exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246110/resultset-next-was-not-called-exception-is-thrown)

And there are more if you do a search...

Hope this helps !!!

Thanks.